# How to loop new request according to response data list from previous step

Tags: karate

I have an API-A, which gets response data like:

```
{
    "people": [
        {
            "id": "A",
            "name": "tom"
        },
        {
            "id": "B",
            "name": "jerry"
        },
        {
            "id": "C",
            "name": "jack"
        }
    ],
    "ids": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
    ]
}
```

And I want to use the data as next step's request payload.
There are maybe two situations here.

1. Use $.people[*].id (p.s. the expression doesn't work, how can I extract the id list easily?)
2. Use $.ids (which gets a list directly)

No matter which case, the id item will be used as a request parameter to start new request API-B.

Sorry I didn't get idea from the readme doc, could anyone give some advice? Thanks.